# Asterisk Pyramid with Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
star = '*'
size = int(input("Enter the height of the pattern (must be greater than 0): "))

def printRow(current_row, max_row) :
    star_count = 2 * current_row - 1

    line = space * (max_row - current_row - 1)

    if current_row == 0 :
        line += "1"
    else :
        line += str(2 * current_row) + space

    line += (star + space) * star_count

    if current_row > 0 :
        line += str(2 * current_row + 1)

    print(line)

if size <= 0 :
    print("Invalid Entry!\n")

for i in range(0, size) :
    printRow(i, size)
```

This is what I have currently, but I would like to convert this into a version that DOES NOT require functions

I am trying to get this as my output

```
                1
            2   *   3
        4   *   *   *   5
    6   *   *   *   *   *   7
8   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   9
```

Comment: _DOES NOT require functions_: why?

Comment: What would `space` be?

Comment: Put `current_row, max_row = i, size` inside your `for` loop and then copy and paste the body of `printRow` underneath it.  Presto, no more functions!

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the function's code and put it in the `for` loop where you have called the function and change the variables accordingly.

```
So, the code would now be:

star = '*'
size = int(input("Enter the height of the pattern (must be greater than 0): "))

if size <= 0 :
    print("Invalid Entry!\n")

for i in range(0, size) :
    star_count = 2 * i - 1

    line = space * (size - i - 1)

    if i == 0 :
        line += "1"
    else :
        line += str(2 * i) + space

    line += (star + space) * star_count

    if i > 0 :
        line += str(2 * i + 1)

    print(line)
```

Note, that you have not declared the variable `space`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not what you want, but this can be implemented with a one-liner:

```
>>> print("\n".join(f"{' '*(16-i*2 if i else 13)}{i if i else ''}   {'*   ' * (i-1)}{i+1}" for i in range(0, 10, 2)))
                1
            2   *   3
        4   *   *   *   5
    6   *   *   *   *   *   7
8   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   9
```